# Assigning values to a mix of jagged array and multidimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I defined a jagged/ multidimensional array.

```
double [][,]Test =new double[2][,];
Test[0]=new double[2,2];
Test[1]=Test[0];
```

And when I assigned the value to `Test[1][1,1]` as:

```
Test[1][1,1]=2;
```

Both of the `Test[0][1,1]` and `Test[1][1,1]` equal to 2.

How to explain this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assigned a reference to the same array to both indexes of the outer array.  As a result, changes to the *one* multidimentional array that you have can be observed by accessing that *one* array from either index of the outer array.